# Adding new number of dictionary based on the value of other dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, lambda

My main objective is as below:

(1) Calculate the number of "id", "id_value". Then find what which value is not present in "id_value" based on "id". Example, "id" = [1,2,3,4],  "id_value"=[1,2]. Then add a new dictionary of "id_value" into the main({"id_value":3},{"id_value":4}).

I tried to use set to find the difference between value within these two variables but with error. Could anyone please assist me.

```
main = [ {
  "y" : {
    "a" : [ {
      "u" : [ {
        "y" : 0
  "x" : [ {
    "check" : {
      "value" : 0
```

My code is as below:

```
forid= []
forvalueid= []

for x in main[0]["x"]:
    for y in x["example"]:
        forid.append(y["id"])
```

I am getting error for "lambda cannot contain assignment"... can I know why?

*** I solved this** Thank you for commenting

Comment: I won't answer "why" since I don't have the expertise. But I can ask: why do you absolutely want to use lambdas? If you need assignments, and lambdas won't let you do it, just define a regular function...

Comment: runnig your code pythone reports: line 45  }] SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html:  lambda functions are syntactically restricted to a single expression.

Comment: I see but is there a way to implement my objective?

Comment: @Humbalan I will edit it now.

Comment: @Joe as I said, just define a regular function instead of trying to use a lambda.

Comment: @Humbalan, I have edited it.

Comment: @Julien I understand that but the problem is I am stuck with how to apply the regular function. Thats why I thought about using lambda but it cant be use to do assignment

Comment: I don't understand your problem: `map(your_function_name, addvalue(forvalueid))`

Comment: @Julien Do you mean something like this? def function(x):
    return lambda x:{y["y"]: x} then I use map(function,addvalue(forvalueid))?

Comment: Before you use lambda please make a few simple examples with lambda functions to understand how lambda works. https://medium.com/@happymishra66/lambda-map-and-filter-in-python-4935f248593

Comment: @Humbalan Thanks, I have read it but still need more practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that will produce what you intend, but this is the lambda free version of your current code:

```
def func(x):
    y["id_value"] = x

map(func, addvalue(forvalueid))
```

Comment: I tried this too but apparently, it produced invalid syntax. But when I changed it to def func(x):
    {y["id_value"]:x} then I get keyerror of "id_value"